# How do i show Objects in PUG Template Engine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm working with NodeJS, Express and some Modules. Now I'm stuck at a Problem with the PUG Template Engine. I cant show my Object that I get from flash messages.

Im sure that I get an Answer of my Process, because I have an Object with the Data I want to show

[image]

But I'm unable to show this Data in my Browser. My Code looks like this at the moment.

```
if message
        div(class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable', style='width: 100%;')
        button(class='close', data-dismiss='alert') &times;
              div(class='row', style='padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 15px;')
                  span(class='oi oi-warning', style='padding: 2px;')                         
                       strong Fehler!
                       hr(class='horizontal-divider')
                       div(class='row', style='padding-left: 15px;')
                              p= message.username
                              p= message.password
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are checking `if message` in the first line, whereas in the response its `msg`.

Secondly, make sure you are pointing the `msg` object correctly, like `array.[0].username.msg`.

Hope this helps.